# Convert Admin Page in web, using webservice for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I want to access admin page through iOS Devices

I am still a beginner in this.

This app have following criteria

1. Login page with admin username and hashed password
2. This login will be processed with POST request
3. After login, it will remain logged for 1 hour ( like cookie, but I don't know how to do that in iOS )
4. After admin logged, the program will simply get all data with JSON

My question:

How to do number 2 and 3 ( POST request and set cookies with iOS ) ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you had tried something and it didn't work, feel free to post it here so people can help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 you have to create a `HTTPRequest` and then you can post this request to a `NSUrl` using `POST` method.
For 3) this should be done by using `NSTimer` you have to check the application state and also The touch events of the user in the application.

Comment: Thank you Divz,
I think the same way, do you have suggestion how to limit the user to get JSON page from the URL, because user can access that using browser. That JSON page information, should only be accessed using App.

Sorry, I know this is a little bit PHP than Obj-C.

Comment: You can achieve it by setting any credential for getting the response.That credential will be send in the HTTPRequest by Post method and you can also use SHA encryption for security.